# Getting an error trying to update user profile in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

am working on a laravel project and I am working on a user update profile, I am getting an error when updating and I can't figure out the solution.

below is the error I am getting

Target class [App\Http\Controllers\UpdateProfileRequest] does not exist.

below is my route in web.php

```
Route::get('users/edit', 'UserController@edit')->name('users.edit');
Route::put('users/update', 'UserController@update')->name('users.update');
```

below is UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function edit()
    {
        return view('users.edit')->with('user', auth()->user());
    }

    public function update(UpdateProfileRequest $request)
    {
        $user = auth()->user();

        $user->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'organization' => $request->organization,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password
        ]);

        return redirect()->back;
    }
}
```

below is my UpdateProfileRequest

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\User;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateProfileRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required',
            'organization'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required'
            
        ];
    }
}
```

below is the edit.blade.php view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="card-text"><img src="{{ asset('img/logo1.jpg') }}" width="60" height="50" class="mx-auto d-block" alt="logo1"></p>
        <hr style="width:50%", size="2", color=3490dc>
            <div class="card">
            <div style="text-align: center; background-color:#3490dc; color:white;" class="card-header"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ __('My Profile') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.update') }}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('PUT')

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-user" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="organization" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-building-o" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Organization') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="organization" type="text" class="form-control @error('organization') is-invalid @enderror" name="organization" value="{{ $user->organization }}" required autocomplete="organization" autofocus>

                           
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-envelope" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ $user->name }}" required autocomplete="email">

                            
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-key" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><i class="fa fa-key" style="color:#3490dc;"></i> {{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Update') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br/>
@include('footer')
@endsection
```

below is the link to the view in app.blade.php

```
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('users.edit') }}"
                         >
                            {{ __('My Profile') }}
                        </a>

                        <form id="edit-form" action="{{ route('users.edit') }}" style="display: none;">
                            @csrf
                        </form>
```

I will appreciate any help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a using.
Add `use UpdateProfileRequest;` at the top.

(this might not be the correct path, try hovering `UpdateProfileRequest` and looking for an `Import class` button)

Comment: when i try 'use UpdateProfileRequest';  i get a different error which says...
Target class [UpdateProfileRequest] does not exist

Comment: Try `use App\Http\Requests\User\UpdateProfileRequest;`. Keep in mind that I don't know how your app is structured so I'm guessing the namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer in seems to be working even though i am getting a different error in my UserController like this...Undefined property: Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::$back

Comment: You should use `return redirect()->back()`

Comment: Hello again...everything is working perfectly fine am now able to edit user profile except that after logging out i cant use the credentials and the updated  records because am getting the error that says "These credentials do not match our records."

Comment: @Daniel well that has to do with your login logic, and if you updated the credentials then they will ofcourse not match.

Answer (score 0):

You must use it on top of `UserController` class:

```
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateProfileRequest;
```

Comment: Am getting a target class not found errror like this..."
Target class [App\Http\Requests\UpdateProfileRequest] does not exist."

Comment: Maybe your `UpdateProfileRequest ` class has another namespace, please add `UpdateProfileRequest .php` file to your question.

Comment: I did include UpdateProfileRequest.php in my question

Comment: Add `UpdateProfileRequest` class at top with proper path to it. If using `vs code` as editor, right click on `UpdateProfileRequest` in update function and select add class. it will auto add it

Comment: I did added it am getting a different error message in my UserController like this...Undefined property: Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::$back

Comment: This is another problem, you should add more details about it.